# Allow duplicate names in google sheets data validation

Tags: google-sheets

I'm requiring duplicate names within a sheet to be read by data validation.

Currently at the minute, if a duplicate first name appears, it won't appear within the drop down menu even if the last name and other data is different, if it views the first column to be a duplicate it won't be an option to select.

Example:

```
John Smith  01/01/2000 - 22/02/2022
John Doe    05/05/2005 - 15/01/2021
John Robert 18/08/1970 - 12/11/2021

It will only read the top one as the second and third "First name" is a duplicate.
```

Here is the link to the test sheet to view what's set up currently - [CLICK ME](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P-SZh3z0-p7yD0YQYij_7qVZjY7yjRENXbrja4ySrLg/edit?usp=sharing)

*Please note the link allows editors for the next hour then it'll be marked as view only*

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Created a work-around solution

Created an entirely new column and created a **join function** [Google Join Functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) `=A2:A&" "&B2:B` was the exact formula made (as seen on the spreadsheet) I then proceeded to change the data validation on the first page (Pretty side) to follow that new data column created instead of the original column it was finding, so it now finds a **full name** eliminating any duplicates (even if there is a duplicate first name) as it seeks for a whole name instead.

I then moved that entire column to the first (A) column and marked it as "Hide" so you don't see that text as it's irrelevant for what I need, then the rest of the "Pretty side" sheet follows the VLOOKUP function currently in place.

The only problem I see having down the future is having the exact same first and last name and a D.O.B being the only difference. Until that happens this will suffice.